# Highcharts - sync crosshair of charts with different width

Tags: highcharts

I try to get a synced crosshair for multiple highcharts each with a different width.

For know the crosshair is syncing on the position of the cursor and not on the position of the point / the xAxis value (which would be prefered). Can anyone give me a hint how to achieve this?

I have changed the synced charts example in the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/3mn4x8uy/

The chart creation:

```
$.each(activity.datasets, function (i, dataset) {

        // Add X values
        dataset.data = Highcharts.map(dataset.data, function (val, j) {
            return [activity.xData[j], val];
        });

        $('<div class="chart">')
            .appendTo('#container')
            .highcharts({
                chart: {
                    marginLeft: 40+i*100, // make different width for each chart
                    spacingTop: 20,
                    spacingBottom: 20
                },
```

sync code

```
$('#container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function (e) {
    var chart,
        point,
        i,
        event;

    for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i = i + 1) {
        chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
        // Find coordinates within the chart
        event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent);
        // Get the hovered point
        point = chart.series[0].searchPoint(event, true);

        if (point) {
            point.highlight(e);
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find an example how to synchronize multiple charts based on xAxis value: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/udtkgs9m/

The code to sync a Plotline over multiple Charts:

```
function syncronizeCrossHairs(chart) {
    var container = jQuery(chart.container),
        offset = container.offset(),
        x, y;

    container.mousemove(function(evt) {
        x = evt.clientX - chart.plotLeft - offset.left;
        y = evt.clientY - chart.plotTop - offset.top;

        var val = chart.xAxis[0].translate(x, true);

        Highcharts.each(Highcharts.charts, function (act_chart) {
            var xAxis = act_chart.xAxis[0];
            xAxis.removePlotLine("myPlotLineId");
            xAxis.addPlotLine({
                value: val,
                width: 1,
                color: 'red',
                //dashStyle: 'dash',                   
                id: "myPlotLineId"
            });
        });
   });
}
```

Comment: You can use the code from example above, implementing this solution on different charts will not be difficult. Plot lines imitate crosshair, you can customize their styles to your needs.